# Need advice about JOIN by LIKE operator

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have two data tables, one contain the customer data such as customer ID and used bonus codes. The second table is for internal notes, every note that i write about the customer is there, for example: gave to customer 12 bonus code GFT100.
know i need join this two table based on the bonus code, i want for every bonus code the player used to find the relevant note in the notes table.

Table 1: Used bonus codes

```
CustomerID | Coupon_Code | DateOfUsege      
--------------------------------------       
    12     |   AAA25     | 2016-09-10         
-------------------------------------
    12     |   BBB13     | 2016-09-10
--------------------------------------
    17     |   CCC14     | 2016-09-10
```

Table2:Customer Notes

```
CustomerID|   Date   |         Text
---------------------------------------------
   12     |2016-09-07| Gave bonus AAA25     
----------------------------------------------
   12     |2016-09-07| Very good customer
----------------------------------------------
   17     |2016-09-06| Gave bonus code CCC14
```

Desired output: for each used code in table 1 add only the relevant note from table 2

```
CustomerID | Coupon_Code | DateOfUsege  |         Text          |    
----------------------------------------------------------------       
    12     |   AAA25     | 2016-09-10   | Gave bonus AAA25      | 
----------------------------------------------------------------
    17     |   CCC14     | 2016-09-10   | Gave bonus code CCC14 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise adding a nullable `coupon_code` column to your notes table (assuming a note may only pertain to zero or one coupon code) and recording the optional code with each note when applicable. Searching for the code in the free text values could return false positives

... but, this join should get you started

```
SELECT a.CustomerID, a.Coupon_Code, a.DateOfUsege, b.Text
FROM `used_bonus_codes` a
INNER JOIN `customer_notes` b
  ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
  AND b.Text LIKE CONCAT('%', a.Coupon_Code, '%')
```